# Insert new line with macros on Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-macros

The React Native Hot Reload on the device doesn't work fine all the time, according to the code you are working with, so we have to reload the app.

Therefore, I'm writing a code snipet to reload my android device always I save a file on Visual Code, like the RN hot reload.

[I've seen this question that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838602/bind-a-keypress-to-a-shell-command-that-uses-the-current-file-in-visual-studio-c)

My doubt is: How can I add a command to my script to add a new line?
Something like: `editor.action.insertNewLine`

Obs: I couldn't find a reference of this, if you have one to suggest I thanks.

```
"macros": {
    "runCommandInTerminal": [
        {
            "command": "cursorMove",
            "args": {
                "to": "wrappedLineEnd",
            }
        },
        "editor.action.insertNewLine",// command to add new line here
        {
            "command": "type",
            "args": {
                "text": "adb shell input text \"RR\" "
            }
        },
        {
            "command": "cursorMove",
            "args": {
                "to": "wrappedLineStart",
                "by": "wrappedLine",
                "value": 1,
                "select": true
            }
        },
        "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        "workbench.action.files.save",
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After search and read the references I found a solution. 
If someone gets interested it's on my GitHub:

https://github.com/LucasMMota/hackings/blob/master/visual-code.md

Answer (score 0):

This is it.

```
"editor.action.insertLineAfter"
```

Thanks to Lucas